# Adding meta tag to a view

Tags: 8, meta-tags

I am working with Drupal 8. I want to add meta tags for title and description for a view. Is there any option?

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable the Metatag Views module (part of [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag))
2. Visit a View edit page
3. Configure your meta tags

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Is Meta tag views module available in drupal8?

Comment: Seems to be, you can just check the project page though

Comment: No meta tag view module in drupal8.

Comment: No? What about the big green one labelled 8.x-1.7 on the project page?

Comment: Oh maybe you didn't see my edit - it's included with the larger Metatag module